# Lightroom 5, photo order is wrong in Develop mode

Tags: adobe-lightroom

When in Develop mode, my opened Catalog or simply imported photos, are not displayed in order.
I am trying to find a "Sort by Name" or similar like I have in Windows, but I cant find it.

This problem is frustrating because I am an event photographer, and I want the beginning of the night to be the first photos I edit. Also, imagine shooting a city for a full weekend. You will end up with many shots of one building, so you want them nicely in a row so you can easily go through all of them. Instead of having to scroll back and forth trying to find all of them.

My question is, how do I sort the order? It should be so easy. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to the Grid Mode, then use the View > Sort menu to set your sorting option.